# Read the pageviews.gz files from wikipedia

Tags: powershell, wikipedia

I wrote a script to download the pagviewsXXXXX.gz files from wikipedia. So fa so good.
When I unzip the files the content is illegible. Any one knows how to read the content of the pagwviews.gz files ? If there is some api or any idea on how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what software you used to decompress the .gz files. I just used 7-zip on a 64-bit Win10 machine with success. Having done that I find that https://dumps.wikimedia.org/other/pagecounts-raw/ provides a description of the lines in the uncompressed file.

The line

```
de Stadio_Arena_Garibaldi_-_Romeo_Anconetani 1 11820
```

is from the de (German) wikipedia, page 'Stadio_Arena_Garibaldi_-_Romeo_Anconetani', which had been referenced once in the hour-long period covered by the gzipped file, and the server returned 11,820 bytes.

This line looks like gibberish.

```
ar %D9%85%D8%B7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%81%D9%8A%D8%A9 1 16742
```

The first two characters, however, indicate that it represents a reference to the Arabic version of wikipedia. The '%' items are non-ascii characters.